# How can I check the users permissions for a specific OU?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to see all the users permissions on a given AD Organizational Unit.
Like in the effective access in the ADUC under Properites -> Security

Thats my input:

```
$aclsuser = (get-acl "AD:$($user.DistinguishedName)").Access
$aclsou = (get-acl "AD:$($ou.DistinguishedName)").Access
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
$ou = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "SomeOU"' -Properties *
$ou.nTSecurityDescriptor.Access |select IdentityReference,AccessControlType
```

Comment: Thats exactly the same output as "$aclsou = (get-acl "AD:$($ou.DistinguishedName)").Access"